# DJANGO PYINSTALLER ISSUE

Tags: python, django, mongodb, pymongo, pyinstaller

I'm trying to compile a Django (3) applications that uses pymongo and channels. I followed steps in a ticket in stackoverflow, I got the .exe file but when I try tu run it using app.exe runserver I got this error :

\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI149762\Test_Project\settings.pyc'
Failed to execute script manage

I've found nothing on the net discussing this issues.

HELP PLEASE.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add --onefile parameter ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Yes I just did it but it does not work neither :/ , still same issue. Would you need my manage.spec and the tree structure of my project?

Comment: Hey! Not working neither. The problem was that django 3.** is not fully supported by pyinstaller so I downgrade and it works.